# How to assign PacketIDs to keep track of packets over an unreliable network using UDP in C?

Tags: c, udp

I'm sorry if the question seems odd. Right now, I have a client sending packets to a server over a reliable network using UDP. For my project, I have to send these packets over an unreliable network using UDP. In order to emulate the unreliable network, I am running `sudo tc qdisc add dev lo root netem delay 100ms 20ms 25% loss 0.5% duplicate 1% reorder 25% 50%`.

Since packets are being dropped and duplicated, I want to assign each packet a PacketID in order to keep track of each packet. If PacketID 5 is skipped, for example, no other packets will be sent until 5 is properly sent. If PacketID 5 is being duplicated, it won't accept the duplicated version.

I feel like I understand the methodology for assigning a PacketID, but I'm fairly new to socket programming and I don't know if there's a more efficient way of doing it. I'm not asking for answers (as this is a project for class), but for some advice and tips as to how I should go about this

Comment: "*a more efficient way of doing it*" use TCP? Why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Using UDP is required for this project

Comment: Ah, student torturing again. I feel pity for you.

Comment: You need to make up a protocol on top of UDP though.

Comment: Yeah it's pretty rough. On the bright side, I'm finally (kind of) understanding how packet sending/receiving works, right?

Comment: What do you mean by making a protocol "on top of" UDP?

Comment: "make up" = invent your self; "on top" = using what UDP provides.

Comment: To understand what a (network) protocol is, you might like to (Also) have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1942371/694576

Comment: Ah right. Yeah, I'm trying. I have a structure that contains the payload and sequence number of my packet, but I'm having trouble connecting the two. I'm sending my packet.payload just fine, but I don't know how to assign the packet.sequenceno to each packet for my server to know when something is duplicated, missing or out of order

Comment: I'll take a look at that link now, thank you

Comment: Start with a piece of paper and a pencil.

Comment: Will do, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledgement packet is needed. Additionally timer can be used.
If receiver gets packet with id n, it will wait for n+1 packet id and it will wait for that until a timer set will expire. all packets with ids greater than n+1 will be dropped. When n+1 packet is received, an acknowledge packet has to be sent from receiver to sender with n+1 in that indicating the packet is received. Sender can wait until ack packet is received.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I see what you're saying, but how would I implement that in code? My packets are sending but I don't know how to check them to see if they made it through correctly

Comment: Receiver will have to send ack packet to sender and sender will know packet has made it through.Further if packet did not reach to receiver, sender will have timer to wait for ack packet. If timeout happens, sender will conclude packet didn’t reach receiver and sender has to retransmit the packet.

Comment: I see what you're saying! Right now I have it sending the packet and the sequence number of the packet to the receiver, and if the receiver doesn't receive pkt.seqno + 1, it returns to the sender "PACKET DROPPED," and now I'm trying to figure out how retransmit a dropped packet. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Just wait on timer at sender for ack packet and if timer times out retransmit the same packet.